"Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size" - counting the number of rows in Sheets with multiple criteria
I am new to Sheets so this might be a straightforward problem. I have a sheet with editions in various states and types. I am trying to count how many editions were created before a particular date for a certain state and type.
Example:



Status
Type
Creation time




New
cust issue
2/19/24


Accepted
bug
2/21/24



I have a formula in sheets using COUNTIFS but I get the error:
Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size.
This is my formula:
= Arrayformula(SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$F$2:$F$2000 ,{"bug","Cust_issue"},'Sheet1'!$G$2:$G$2000 ,"<" &DATE, 'Sheet1'!$E$2:$E$2000, {"assigned","accepted","new","fixed","verified"})))

What am I doing wrong? The ranges are all the same.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is unclear what you are trying to do, especially regarding whether you want to combine the criteria with and or or. Please show say 10 rows of sample data and your desired results from some sample criteria. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Share a sample file.

Here's the issue: your ranges are indeed of the same size, but the criteria inside the curly brackets {} must also be the same in number.
I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but the simplest one would be to repeat values to artificially match the largest criteria set:
= Arrayformula(SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$F$2:$F$2000, {"bug","Cust_issue","bug","Cust_issue","bug"},'Sheet1'!$G$2:$G$2000, "<"&DATE(2024, 10, 03), 'Sheet1'!$E$2:$E$2000, {"assigned","accepted","new","fixed","verified"})))

Notice two things:

your formula will match the exact criteria strings you pass to it - albeit being case-insensitive. So right now, the "cust issue" in your sample table wouldn't be matched since it is not the same than cust_issue;
I added today's date to the DATE function since, being a function, it must take arguments in the DATE(year, month, day) format.

EDIT - Here is an alternative formula which uses regular expressions that you could try:
=ROWS(FILTER('Sheet1'!$E$2:$G$2000, REGEXMATCH('Sheet1'!$F$2:$F$2000, "^(?i)(?:bug|Cust_issue)$"),'Sheet1'!$G$2:$G$2000 < DATE(2024, 10, 03), REGEXMATCH('Sheet1'!$E$2:$E$2000, "^(?i)(?:assigned|accepted|new|fixed|verified)$")))

References

REGEXMATCH
FILTER
ROWS


Thank you so much, I found the alternative to be more accurate than the first. Atleast now I know reason for the error

@ARNN if it solved your issue, know you can accept an answer.
